# DataGrid's ItemsSource Binding window empty using LINQ to SQL Classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq-to-sql, itemssource

I'm using a Microsoft SQL Server database with LINQ to SQL Classes. Everything works well in the code when I make LINQ calls.

The only thing missing is that I'd like to bind the ItemsSource property of my DataGrid to my table's collection. But when I click on the ItemsSource in the property window, there's nothing about that collection.

Any idea how to make it appear in it so I could use it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the designer and just setting the binding source at runtime? Does that work?

Comment: Yes I did, but I'd like it to work with the designer. Like I said in my question, when I play with it in the code it works fine. I just wonder what's missing for it to work in the designer. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you have to Add a "Project DataSource" and then simply choose Object.

Make sure everything is compiled first.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I guess so. Now I added my object in the data sources but I can't get the rest of it... How can I use it in the binding panel  of my datagrid? thx!

Comment: This to broad form me to help you. I know I've done this but it's some time ago.